# How to: sort NSArray by date in descending order with nil date left on top of result set

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I have the following method where self.orderHeader.meetings is a core data NSManagedObject with meetings being a list of metting. The method sorts the meetings by date (meetingDate):

```
- (NSArray *)sortMeetingList {
    return [[self.orderHeader.meetings allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"meetingDate" ascending:NO]]];
}
```

It returns what I want *except* for meeting objects that do not have a meetingDate set. These are left at the bottom of the list, but (given the descending order) I would like to have them shown on top of the list:

So for example: [nil, 2014-12-29, 2014-12-24] instead of [2014-12-29, 2014-12-24, nil]

Is there an easy way to do this ??

Comment: Are you sure that you have nil in NSArray ?

Comment: Quite simple:  Read the documentation for NSArray.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
NSArray *sortedMeetings = [unsortedMeetings sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(MeetingObjectClass *obj1, MeetingObjectClass *obj2) {
    if (!obj1.meetingDate)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    if (!obj2.meetingDate)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    return [obj2.meetingDate compare:obj1.meetingDate];
}];
```

Comment: I was going to suggest the exact same thing but you beat me to it. (Voted)

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly replace the nil dates with [NSDate distantFuture]

Answer (score 0):

Use a different approach to sorting so that you can explicitly specify how to deal with each comparison, such as by using `sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:`.